# Why do some programming languages have break statements, but not higher-order break statements?

Tags: language-features, loops, control-structures

I may have been exposed to exactly the wrong languages, but though many have loops and break statements, none of the languages I am familiar with have higher-order break statements¹. While a regular break statement terminates the innermost loop inside which it is executed, such a `break(n)` statement would terminate the `n` innermost loops.

For example using such a statement, I could write in Python:

```python
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        if foo(i,j):
            break(2)
```

As Python lacks such a statement, however, I have to do something like the following:

```python
broken = False
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        if foo(i,j):
            broken = True
            break
    if broken:
        break
```

(I am aware that there [are other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2597104/2127008) to do this, such as raising exceptions. This serves just as an example.)

In another example, this is [one of the prominent reasons to use a `goto` statement in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245801/2127008). While `goto` allows for a close equivalent of a higher-order break, it introduces a new syntactical element (unless one already uses `goto`s). Not to forget that `goto` is frowned upon by many – be it justified or not.

While I see that using a higher-order break statement is not something most people use on a daily basis, this also applies to a lot of other language features. Also, a higher-order break statement does not seem difficult to implement to me and would be rather intuitive to use.

**Is there a good reason why programming languages would have a break statement but not a higher-order break statement?** I am thinking of things like inherent conceptual problems, broken paradigms or error vulnerability.

---

<sup>¹ Though, when researching for this question, I learnt that PHP has them.</sup>

Comment: Perl and Java both have this.

Comment: Most languages have *labelled* break statements, which are more explicit and in my opinion much preferable.

Comment: Because having boatloads of nested blocks and using `break` in the first place are both ill-advised? (The latter more debatably) Languages have enough challenges without solving problems that people shouldn't be doing anyways.

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise" (help/dont-ask]). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: Some languages have `goto`, others have `call/cc`, or `throw` (and *C* has `longjmp`) ....

Comment: FYI: If you were actually wanting to do this in Python, you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  But then you lose control of breaking out of an inner loop only.

Comment: "higher ordered" is not a good term for this... it has another meaning in computer science

Comment: @Telastyn: I am interested in the case where the language already has a break statement and I use it, whether you like that or not. Discussing break in general is arguably out of place here.

Comment: @gnat: While I see why it may have left the impression, I did not feel any ranty when writing this but am honestly interested as to why there are any specific reasons not to have higher-order breaks (if you already have breaks).

Comment: And some languages even have [BREAK statements that break completely unexpected things](http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/reference/c53g01c/ngfc7b7.html). If you want to break, you have to [EXIT the loop](http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/reference/c53g01c/ngff79f.html). Just for the records. :-)

Comment: For the issues with the design of the break statement for a given language, you had best talk to the language designers for each language.  There are specific things that went into the design that we can only guess about and may not even be an issue on today's architecture.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a good reason why so few programming languages have higher-order break statements?

Using SO tags as the metric, the seven most popular programming languages in use today are Java, C#, Javascript, PHP, Python, C++, and Objective C. Of these languages,

- Java and Javascript have labeled `break`
- C++, [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx), and Objective C have `goto`, which is a more general control statement that solves the same problem. They also all have `break`, naturally, but [no multi-level or labeled break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)
- PHP has both nested (multi-level) `break` and `goto`
- and Python is the odd man out with no `goto` and no labeled `break`.

So maybe a better question is,

**Why doesn't Python have `goto` or labeled `break`?** ;)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python) has an answer to that question:

> Guido rejected it because "code so complicated to require this feature is very rare". The PEP does mention some workarounds, though (such as the exception technique), while Guido feels refactoring to use return will be simpler in most cases.

Personally, I think Python should have one or both, but that is opinionated so don't take it as part of this answer.

Comment: C# also has `break` and `continue`.  `goto` is very rarely used, usually to patch multiple `case` statements together.

Comment: One of the answers of interest to the question cited about Python's reasoning: `PEP 3136 proposes labeled break/continue. Guido rejected it because "code so complicated to require this feature is very rare". The PEP does mention some workarounds, though (such as the exception technique), while Guido feels refactoring to use return will be simpler in most cases.`

http://stackoverflow.com/a/190070/279112

Comment: That being said, I would **never** use a `try...catch` to do something like that, as has been cited in the question on this thread and seemingly that answer.  Exceptions/errors should only be used for exceptions and errors.

Comment: Thx @Panzercrisis, I have edited to quote the interesting part you spotted.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Exceptions are cheap and idiomatic in Python, and "exceptions and errors" is subjective. To you a file being missing may be an error; to me that's expected behavior (because you can't make any assumptions about the state of the world outside your process).

Comment: Couldn't the question just as easily be *Why do Python programmers post so many questions to StackOverflow despite Python not having `break`?* Questions are squeaky wheels. SO tags correlate with the frequency with which someone seeks help with a problem they are experiencing. That's a function of popularity, language design, and language documentation.

Comment: In most cases `return` would be a sufficient `break` at the method level.

Answer (score -2):

Because `while` and `until` provide clearer semantics. They provide higher level abstractions for expressing programmer intent. The semantics of `break` are imperative at the lower level of instructions to the computer. They are closer to that of machine code - like `goto`, `break` is thin syntactic sugar over `JMP`.

McConnell's basic advice:

> **When to Use a `for` Loop.**  If you have a condition under which execution has to jump out of a loop, use a `while` loop
>   instead....Most complicated looping tasks are better handled by a
>   `while` loop. -- Code Complete [first edition] pp 329.

This is really just an extension of his more general advice:

> **Use `break` and `continue` only with caution.** Use of `break`
>   eliminates the possibility of treating a loop as a black box. Limiting
>   yourself to only one statement to control a loop's exit condition is a
>   powerful way to simplify your loops. Using `break` forces the person
>   reading your code to look inside the loop for an understanding of the
>   loop control. This makes the loop more difficult to understand. 
>   -- Code Complete [first edition] pp 337-338.

In the end his "key point" is:

> Minimize the number of factors that affect the loop. Simplify!
>   Simplify! Simplify! Second treat the inside of the loop as if it were
>   a routine -- keep as much of the control as possible outside the loop.
>   Explicitly state the conditions under which the body of the loop is to
>   be executed. Don't make the reader look inside the loop to understand
>   the loop control. Think of a loop as a black box: The surrounding
>   program knows the control conditions but not the contents.

Comment: It's a shame that, after all this time, some folks still think that deeply nested `if/else` statements are somehow clearer than a well-placed `break` or `continue`, or that a single point of exit is still preferable to a [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause).

Comment: Python unlike many other languages, loves the idea of "one true way". In the rest of the world, things are not always so hard and fast. Even *Code Complete* admits as much. But it still recommends `while` and `until` as the best first approach. Then `cond\case\switch`. And only then, treating something as a corner case. Deeply nested `if..then..else` does not get much love. Socartes and 孔夫子 beat you to complaining about youth by 2.5 millennia. YMMV.

Comment: When I use `break` and `continue`, they express my intent just fine thankyouverymuch.

Comment: I was answering the question in the abstract so that someone googling might find a useful answer. Sure it's unfortunate that it doesn't make someone already inclined to express their intent using `break` happy. That's the price of a cup of coffee I suppose.

Comment: Could you please back up the opinions expressed in this answer with objective facts or reliable sources? As it stands, another user could simply post a contradicting answer like “*Using `break` clearly expresses programmer intent and is on a much higher level than `goto`. Setting boolean flags to break out of nested loops is far less clear than using a labeled `break`*”.

Comment: The question references Python, if it were C or x86 assembly then the question would be incoherent. We're already talking about languages at a level of abstraction above that where flags and semaphores and pointer dereferences are consistent with the language design - we're outside the realm where "C in any language" is practical.

Comment: "Syntactic sugar" is always used to downgrade some aspect of a language with no good reason.  Why doesn't anyone complain that 'if' is syntactic sugar over a conditional JMP (shudder...) and 'while' is just syntactic sugar over a conditional JMP with another JMP going backwards (yikes)?

Comment: @FlorianF I said "thin syntactic sugar". It was a remark on the degree of abstraction `break` provides. Even `JMP`, as an assembly language instruction is syntactic sugar for machine code (or perhaps a CISC bytecode running on a RISC processor). Programming languages don't contain magic beans. It's Domain Specific Languages all the way down until you get to flip-flops.

Comment: A break within a try{...}finally{...} within a for loop will still run the finally block.  Therefore, break is more than a jump.  It is a clean exit from a block of code.  (Or even simpler, it will release block-local variables).

Comment: @FlorianF Sure. So will `while` or `until`, and they will always place the conditional test in a syntactically determined location not an arbitrary one. The cleanup is still done by `try...catch` even in languages like Python that don't have `break`.